# TLS/SSL settings cert in azure function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was trying to see if the purpose of this TLS/SSL settings in function app is similar to the cert store? i.e. can we store a public cert in this section of the function app and let function app access the public cert in the code by getting the cert from this location? If yes, is there any sample that I can take a look into?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> if the purpose of this TLS/SSL settings in function app is similar to
> the cert store?

The purpose of this TLS/SSL settings in function app is not similar to the cert store.

A certificate uploaded into an app is stored in a deployment unit that is bound to the app service plan's resource group and region combination (internally called a *webspace*). This makes the certificate accessible to other apps in the same resource group and region combination.

If you are using cert store( key vault ) to store you ssl certificates then you need to pass the key vault certificate uri as application setting to the functions app.

> can we store a public cert in this section of the function app and let
> function app access the public cert in the code by getting the cert
> from this location? If yes, is there any sample that I can take a look
> into?

As per the Azure documentation , you can store the public cert under the function app ttl/ssl settings & refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-windows-apps) for accessing the certificate in your application code.