# Azure function Error : received an unexpected eof or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I have a requirement where I am calling an API (programmatically PUT Method) from another API.
Both of the APIs are hosted as Azure Function App.
The request has nearly 600 rows.

The below method call is throwing the error: **received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream**

If I send a request say 100-150 rows, it processes successfully.

I think that it is nothing to do with the code, it is related to the Azure Function app.

Please let me know if I need to add any configuration to the Azure Function app.

Thanks in Advance.

```
public async Task<List<CarPricing>> TestMethod(CarPricingModel request, string resourcePath,string token)
        {
            
            try
            {
                using var stream = StreamUtility.GenerateStreamFromString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));

                using var data= new StreamContent(stream);
                data.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                   {"id", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } 
                };
                var relativeUrl = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(resourcePath, queryParams);

                using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Put,
                    Content = content,
                    RequestUri = new Uri(relativeUrl, UriKind.Relative)
                };

               
                var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                httpStatusCode = httpResponseMessage.StatusCode;


                var httpResponse = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                using var responseContent = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(httpResponse));
                var response = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<List<CarPricing>>(responseContent);

                return response;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.LogError("API error {err_msg}",ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add this call before request:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl`

Comment: Tried ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
SSL is deprecated.
Error:
 System.Net.ServicePoint: The requested security protocol is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps that might help to fix the issue:

> received an unexpected eof or 0 bytes from the transport stream

- This error generally occurs during the HTTP Calls of .NET Core Applications.
- TLS/SSL binding is supported in the Azure Function App. You can bind it through Azure Portal and using the Code.
- If you’re using the HTTPS Protocol, apply this SSL Call before the request made as mentioned in the comments:

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

or

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3| SecurityProtocolType.Tls| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

but the above error might come for many causes such as:

- Client IP may be restricted, which you can add in Access Restrictions of the Function app API.
- Typo Mistake or Incorrect URL of the API that is called programmatically from another Azure Function API.

Refer to this MS [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code) for using the TLS/SSL Certificate Programmatically and SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379543/tls-ssl-settings-cert-in-azure-function-app) that shows how to use the TLS/SSL Certificate in Azure Function App.